# Running Multiple exe console applications that stay open within C++

Tags: exe

I am working with an API within my own C++ program that communicates with a 3rd party application of the API through a server -client relationship of a TCP connection.  At this time, I have to manually open the server console application (.exe) first, followed by the client console application (also .exe).  Both these windows must remain open in the background throughout my application in order to perform the necessary tasks.

I would like to automate the execution of these two .exe's in the order that I have presented above.  I have tried two consecutive ShellExecute() Windows API function calls, I have tried the old system() function and I have tried opening a batch file like this: 
ShellExecute(NULL,"open","ocrtext.bat",NULL,NULL,SW_SHOW);

Where the batch file goes something like this: 
START c:\videoocr\server\ocrD.exe
START /w c:\videoocr\server\ocrGW.exe

The same problem exists with all these options:  The server console window opens fine, but the client window fails to open.   I suspect that the problem has to do with an inability to call multiple console applications that each stay open with these methods.

What can I do?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `ShellExecuteEx` or `CreateProcess` to run the server console directly (using its EXE path). Pass the server process handle to `WaitForInputIdle` function with `INFINITE` or limited time. Then execute the client console directly (using its EXE path).

Comment: I apologize, but I don't follow you here.  Can you give a coded example?  Where do I get the server process handle from?

Answer (score 0):

call the application in your batch file with this command:

```
start "App1" /min cmd.exe /c startApp1.exe
start "App2" /min cmd.exe /c startApp2.exe
...
```

With this a batch file can open different consoles.

Comment: This does not work.  Only "App1" opens.  I discovered that App2 does not open because it receives an error that says, "host failed to load."  To get even that error, I had to simply write `c:\startApp2.exe` in the batch file followed by `pause`.  When I double click on the program in its directory it opens fine.  I check the spelling and path of the file and it is correct. Using your command for "App2", I found that /c modifier does not work at all, but /b at least gets me to the error of "host failed to load".  I have no idea what /b does, I tried it based on another suggestion.